# How to add custom scripts to the MDT?

Tags: powershell, mdt

I have setup MDT using the steps provided in this [link](https://www.deploymentresearch.com/cloud-os-deployment-part-2-bare-metal-deployment-via-mdt-from-the-cloud/)

When I am trying to edit the task sequence and add my own script, the ps1 file is not downloading on the target machine and not running.

Attached the screenshot.

I copied the ps1 file to Deployment share\scripts folder
[image: ts]

Answer (score 1):

- First thing, I would crate a separate folder for custom scripts, and place it after Windows Update step.
- Then create new step and chose **`Run PowerShell Script`** not **`Run Command Line`** option.
- Then enter a path to the script in **`PowerShell script`** field, just the path.
- Then add the **`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`** in **`Parameter**`** field.
- Be shore that the path to the script is accessible to MDT Deployment.

Comment: Configure is a default action, why replication of that doesn't work?

Comment: First step you mentioned to create a folder and place it. I didn't see any create folder step and copy these scripts. Can you guide